# How to use relationships in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

my question has two parts

Firstly, My if statement is not working. My if statement is as followed:

```
if ($request->is_published) {
            $resources_page->published_at = now();
        }
```

This is stored in my controller, I have a model for this and it is as followed:

```
public function is_published()
    {
        return $this->published_at !== null;
    }
```

It is meant to check whether my checkbox is checked and return the timestamp, I have it cast in my model like followed:

```
protected $casts = [
        'published_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
```

And in my view:

```
@include('components.form.input-checkbox', [
                            'label' => 'Publish?',
                            'form_object' => 'page',
                            'name' => 'is_published'
                            ])
```

Could anyone elude to the answer?

Secondly, when trying to sync, it is not storing to my resources_category_resources_page table
In my controller, i have the following code

```
$resources_page->resources_categories()->sync(
            ResourcesCategory::whereIn('slug', $request->resources_categories)->pluck('id')
        );
```

In my model I have the relationships declared properly, so I don't know why its not storing?

Comment: Are you doing `$resources_page->save()` somewhere after setting `$resources_page->published_at`? Do you see the `published_at` value get saved in the database?

Comment: yes, the page is being saved and no value is being inputted to database
`
if ($request->is_published) {
            $resources_page->published_at = now();
        }

        $resources_page->save();

Comment: But `is_published` is based off `published_at`. You've got circular logic.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean?